# VSCode hyperlink between results in one file to different file:line

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, hyperlink

I have some search results stored in a file, say results.foo. These results provide the file name and line number of each matching result. They look something like this:

```
bar1.c@123, bar2.c@678,
bar2.c@2345, bar3.c@444
```

What I'd like to do is, open results.foo in VSCode, have it scan the file (based on the extension), and "know" that clicking on the "123" in results.foo should open file bar1.c to line 123.

problemMatcher gets very close, but this seems action oriented (must invoke an external tool?) and would probably rely on the output window inside VS Code. I have created/used that type of operation inside Visual Studio IDE, but was hoping for simpler, file-to-file linking... Thanks!

Comment: write a task that `cat`s the file to the terminal and add a problem matcher, only one problem per line allowed, so maybe write a small script to split the file to individual files

Comment: Thanks @rioV8. I'm still new to VS Code and I seem to be bogged down with workspaces. Seems you have to have a workspace to create a tasks.json file, but I wanted to make this hyperlink "tool" available to any directory and not just under source control. If I try to Run Task from just the results file opened with code results.foo, I get "Tasks are only available from a workspace folder". I'd appreciate suggestions as to working around this...

Comment: Workspace === Project, you somehow need to tell the editor which files belong together. Some projects in language X you want to start differently. You can't control all this from a global settings/task/launch files. How do you share settings/tasks/launch with team members, they do not need to know all your other stuff.

Comment: Thanks again. I have it working, but it's unbelievably kludgey: I'm copying tasks.json into a new .vscode subdirectory and adding the sourcefiles to the workspace. Is that the minimum of what I'll have to to whenever wanting to use this hyperlinking capability? It's how I interpreted your "you can't control all this from a global settings..." but there could be a better interpretation :-)

Comment: I'm modifying a plugin where it would be a bit easier but the `results.foo` file also then needs to be in the workspace because the file does not contain complete paths to the files. It would be a maintain mess if you have 20+ projects and all there specific tasks and launch settings are in global files. The same is that each project has its own SCM.

Comment: This is in a support role where we're looking at customers' code or sometimes open source code. So we're not really building it, hence the lack of formal source control. The files are usually in a single directory, so I was hoping to use something like ${cwd} when opening results.foo, which could be stuck in that same directory. The search results, at present, produce relative paths, but I am intrigued by your saying this could be different if the results file contained complete paths?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218841/discussion-between-cniggeler-and-riov8).

Comment: Any chance you could change the files to somefile.c:123 so the @ is replaced by :? Easier, I have it working like that (for relative paths of course).  It also works for the `somefile@123` form but is more than twice as long.

Comment: If you use the task option you can put the Task in the Global `tasks.json`. Use command: `Tasks: Open User Tasks` and choose `Other`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) v0.7.0. It does more than only HTML files.

To create a view with the links you can add the following setting (Global or Workspace)

```
  "html-related-links.include": {
    "all": [
      { "find": "([-\\w.]+)@(\\d+)", "lineNr": "$2" },
      { "find": "([-\\w.]+):(\\d+):(\\d+)", "lineNr": "$2", "charPos": "$3" }
    ]
  }
```

I also added a case if there is also a character position avaiable.

You have to set `html-related-links.alwaysShow` to true.

With a next release you can lock the content to a file.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I put the above info in settings.json and opened results.foo, but there are no hyperlinks. I looked at the readme for the extension but didn't see anything obvious that I missed. Can you elaborate on what's needed to get it to activate?

Comment: It shows a view in the Explorer sidebar. See the extension image bottom left. Have you set the `alwaysShow`. What does your settings.json look like? If you open a html file with links do you see them?

Comment: Thanks - it is working! "HTML Related Links" in the sidebar is collapsed by default and at the very bottom of the VSCode window - I didn't even see it until you told me to look there.

Comment: @cniggeler: with v0.8.0 you can lock the view content to a file

Answer (score 1):

I greatly simplified this via a new option I added to an extension I wrote: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).

Here is a working keybinding:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+q",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "description": "Open file at line number",

    "find": "([.\\w\\\\/]+?)@(\\d*)",
    "isRegex": true,
    "restrictFind": "matchAroundCursor",
    
    "postCommands": [
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          // send the filename:lineNumber to the terminal
          // the capture groups and variables are resolved
          "text": "code -g '${workspaceFolder}${pathSeparator}$1:$2'\u000D"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This will look for the find regex that matches around the cursor position, thanks to the `matchAroundCursor` option.

Then it will run the `postCommand` which is `sendSequence` - but the `$1` and `$2` in it will be replaced by the capture groups from the find regex.

---

If you want another approach that uses the full power of the vscode extension api and not a `postCommand` consider this:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+q",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "description": "Open file at line number",

    "find": "([.\\w\\\\/]+?)@(\\d*)",
    "isRegex": true,
    "restrictFind": "matchAroundCursor",

    "run": [
      "$${",
        "const pos = new vscode.Position($2-1, 0);",  // Position and thus Range is 0-based, so subtract 1
        "const range = new vscode.Range(pos, pos);",
        "const options = { selection:range, preview:false };",  // 
        "const wsFolderUri = await vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri;", // relative to first workspaceFolder
        "const uri = await vscode.Uri.joinPath(wsFolderUri, '$1');",
        "await vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', uri, options);",
        
        //  or use the simpler below. quickOpen is 1-based
        // "await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.quickOpen', `$1:$2`);",  // works but opens the quickOpen
      "}$$",
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Minor correction and is now working! The setting for multi-command sends "gotoLineSelect" while that tag was named "gotoLineNumberSelect" in Select By setting.

Comment: I think this approach can be generalized (i.e., no workspace) by changing the send sequence to `code -g ${relativeFileDirname}\\${selectedText}`. However, the selection of the filename includes embedded spaces from the start of the line, causing the command to become `code -g c:\path\to\                              file.c:123`. The culprit is `"moveby": "^|(?<=, )"`; I know perl regex pretty well but I can't really decipher this. Can the leading spaces be trimmed? Thanks again!

Comment: I like the terminal command construction. If there are leading spaces at the beginning of the line or more spaces after the `,` you can change the regex to `"^ *|(?<=, *)"`

Comment: I reworked and simplified it.  The spaces before the filename are handled simply now with the `forward` and `forwardNext` combination in the `fileNameSelect` code.  (thanks to @rioV8 again) I added single quotes to the folder\\filename so that if they have spaces in them (see the demo) it still works.  And I added a clear command to the terminal - which may be preferable to some.  You can also put your cursor before the first file or after the last file in a row and it works.

Comment: Very nice! As to tickmarks: had to add opening tickmark to the "code path/name" sequence and the closing tickmark after the line number in the separate sequence. Otherwise I got the error, "Arguments in `--goto` mode should be in the format of `FILE(:LINE(:CHARACTER))`."

Comment: Hmm, I certainly tried that location too and that error message was hard to get rid of - I thought I had it though.  But the single quotes are only necessary if you have folders or filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: If I load the results file in a brand new VS Code session a la "code results.foo" and try to do the hyperlink by typing <ALT-Y>, nothing happens! BUT, if from the VS Code menu I select Terminal - New Terminal, <ALT-Y> starts working as expected. Furthermore, I can close the Terminal window and <ALT-Y> continues to work! Can anyone explain why that is, or more importantly, somehow enable Terminal on the startup of VS Code?