# Run commands in the terminal from a vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
// want run command
// ~/zcfh/umlgen/build/bin/umlgen /Users/zcfh/zcfh/tmp1.cpp -o=~/zcfh/t.txt
const ls = spawn('~/zcfh/umlgen/build/bin/umlgen ', ['/Users/zcfh/zcfh/tmp1.cpp',"-o=~/zcfh/t.txt"]);
```

It seems that using `child_process` you can run commands in the terminal. I want to be able to run a binary program in the terminal. Any good comments or references?

Comment: use `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` https://stackoverflow.com/a/63163335/9938317

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the above via using the **vscode.window** api below is the sample code:

```js
let t = vscode.window.createTerminal();
// new line is added by default to execute
t.sendText(`dotnet new console -o ${path}`);
```

Below is my VS code version info

```
Version: 1.75.1 (user setup)
Commit: 441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
Date: 2023-02-08T21:32:34.589Z
Electron: 19.1.9
Chromium: 102.0.5005.194
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Sandboxed: No
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { execFile } = require('child_process');

let errMessage: string = "";

const umlgen = execFile(cmd, args, { cwd: workingPath });
umlgen.stdout.on('data', (data: Uint8Array) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
umlgen.stderr.on('data', (data: Uint8Array) => {
console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});
umlgen.on('close', (code: number) => {
    console.log(`close: ${code}`);
});
```